# Nested ifelse in column containing dates in R

Tags: r, datetime, for-loop, if-statement, nested-if

I am new to R and I am trying a simple nested `ifelse` operation, where I want the `view_date` should lie between `start_date` and `end_date`.

I used to do this in excel, but since the data set is too large for excel to handle, I am switching it to R. Can you help me with that?

**Query:**

```
df1$check <- ifelse(df1$view_date>=df1$start_date,
  ifelse(df1$view_date<=df1$end_date,1,0),0)
```

> Error: Error in charToDate(x) :
> character string is not in a standard unambiguous format**

Comment: Can you try `df1$view_date <- as.Date(df1$view_date)`  `df1$start_date <- as.Date(df1$start_date)` and `df1$end_date <- as.Date(df1$end_date)`? I'm not sure that your date thing's format is not shown.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here a `tidyverse` approach with `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(check = case_when(
    view_date >= start_date & view_date <= end_date ~ 1
    view_date >= start_date & view_date  > end_date ~ 0,
    TRUE ~ 0
   ))
```